# Elasticsearch python api time range with specific field values

Tags: python, elasticsearch

Im trying to write a query for elasticsearch where im searching in a specific time range for the specific names of a field called "name".

I came up with:

```
body = {
    "query": {
        "range": {
                'timeObject': {
                    "from": '2018-01-01T20:10:30',
                    "to": '2023-03-01T20:10:30'
                }},
        "bool": {
            "filter": {
                "terms": {
                    "name": ["Anna", "Peter", "Bob", "John"]
                }
            }
        }
```

But i get the error: elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: RequestError(400, 'parsing_exception', '[range] malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME]')

What do I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is put range query inside filter clause. The [filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-filter-context.html#query-filter-context-ex) is array you must user "filter": [{..}]

Ex:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "range": {
            "timeObject": {
              "from": "2018-01-01T20:10:30",
              "to": "2023-03-01T20:10:30"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "name": [
              "Anna",
              "Peter",
              "Bob",
              "John"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```